Turn off NFC permission for specific app?
When I put an NFC card near my Android 14 phone, a specific app (that I do not want being able to skim the data of every card I use with my phone) opens.  Can I turn off "NFC read permission" for a specific app?  This seems like a big security issue, and given that I can control camera, microphone, location, etc. permissions for specific apps, I'm surprised I haven't been able to find any information on preventing a given app from receiving NFC read info.  I want to be able to use NFC via other apps, so turning it off entirely is not helpful.

Go to Settings > Apps > Special app access > Launch via NFC > [specific app] and there is a toggle on/off
